# Trap a window close

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel one may open more than one window to view the same workbook:

- manually <kbd>View</kbd>  > <kbd>New Window</kbd>
- or programmatically `ThisWorkBook.NewWindow` etc.

One can then trap a change in window activation via the `Workbook_WindowDeactivate(ByVal Wn As Window)` event.

But is there a way in Excel VBA to detect if a user attempts to close a specific window?

Note that this is *not* the same thing as  closing the entire workbook.

Comment: Got it. Never played with that "new window" feature before.

Comment: May I ask *why* you are trying to trap window closures?

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN for Excel 2007, "*The Windows collection for the Application object contains all the windows in the application...*" (ref [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210370%28v=office.12%29.aspx), but beware of broken links in MSDN - you may have to search for "Window Object" in MSDN).

It sounds like you're not concerned with detecting a userform, so the Application.Windows collection could be used. Loop through all windows during an event, and check if a window in the collection matches your criteria to see if that window is open or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That's easy enough to do, but I can't really use it to prevent a window from being closed in the first place. On the basis of some event or another I could do that sort of scan and reopen a window if I found it didn't exist (so had been closed) but not quite what I"m trying to do.